# I have form with lot of field in and what I need is the form data should be in single array

Tags: php, forms, field, symfony, naming

I have form with lot of field in and what I need is the form data should be in single array.

For example: Let's suppose the form fields names are `name`, `username`, `password`, etc. and I need to get these all fields inside a array named `$user` likes this:

```
$user = array('name' => 'foo', 'password' => 'bar', ...);
```

So I give form field names as `$user['name']` but it show a error message like:

> The name contains illegal characters. Names should start with a letter, digit or underscore and only contain letters, digits, numbers, underscores ("_"), hyphens ("-") and colons (":").

Can any one help me to figure it out?

Comment: Show the **exact error** in your question.  "Errors like" isn't very useful.  PHP itself doesn't throw these errors, so I'm guessing it's symfony....

Comment: @cale_b yes these message are shown from symfony

Comment: Sounds like you want this: http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html

Comment: **This is a duplicate** and should be closed as such: http://stackoverflow.com/q/13258352/870729

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Name your elements like this:

```
user[name]
user[password]
```

Do not use `$` do not use `'`.

`$` is just for PHP variables, not HTML form elements.

Including quotes within the name will just make the keys on your $_POST array look ugly, so don't use them (apparently symphony won't let you anyways).

Notice without quotes:

```
<input type="text" name="user[name]"/>
<input type="text" name="user[password]"/>

array(1) {
  ["user"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(11) "Super Admin"
    ["password"]=>
    string(8) "PaSsWoRd"
  }
}
```

with single quotes:

```
<input type="text" name="user['name']"/>
<input type="text" name="user['password']"/>

array(1) {
  ["user"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["\'name\'"]=>
    string(11) "Super Admin"
    ["\'password\'"]=>
    string(8) "PaSsWoRd"
  }
}
```

See how the backslashes are included to escape the quotes... ugly.